# Real time updated in Salesforce from external application using Database/API

Tags: api

Scenario: I have a list:

- user (name)
- status (accepted, arrived, on progress, completed, payment from Stipe (if paid send email thank you, if not send reminder email) ).

When I trigger (status) from my external app, It should update status on Salesforce real-time automatically. Is there a way I can do that on Salesforce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can develop a REST API in Salesforce and call it from external app when you are trigger the status and update the same in Salesforce.

Is it possible for you to call the Salesforce exposed REST API from your external System?

Comment: Yes, I can call Salesforce API from my external application. hmm so I would also need to build a new lightning app or trailhead app on Salesforce then build Rest API then use that API from my external app?

Comment: You must be having existing Salesforce App, you just need to add Apex class which will be exposed as a REST API. To understand how to develop REST API refer [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_code_sample_basic.htm) and  [link] (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_user_tasks.htm)